# Specific mixed feature between offset, buffer and intersection

Tags: qgis, buffer, intersection, offset

I'm trying to reproduce the steps needed to aim this goal: Given a layer of polygons, I'm want to retrieve for each polygon which is at a distance less than 50m to a 2nd polygonal layer the only 5m band in the polygon facing the items of the second layer.

Quite complicated explanations...I know....so, a drawing is a better way to explain myself.
I want to build the red parts (the 5m band of the orange layer polygons facing the green ones, when they're at a distance less than 50m)....How would you do that with QGIS?

[image]

Comment: When the red ones are at less than 50'? Or the orange ones? And what part--edge, centroid?

Comment: When the orange polygon are less than 50 (those 50 are pictured by the green boundaries). The criteria is obviously an simple "intersect"